# parsing json with jquery to populate datalist

Tags: jquery, json, html, parsing, html-datalist

I want to populate a datalist based on JSON data to create an autocomplete field.

I have managed to get the following to work thanks to a [this tuotorial](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/6/14/Example-of-a-dynamic-HTML5-datalist-control):

This json data:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ARTNAME"],"DATA":[["Morning Forest"],["Morph"],["Mountains"],["Mom"]]}
```

I can parse fine using this code:
    
$(document).ready(function() {

```
if(document.createElement("datalist").options) {

    $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val === "") return;
        //You could use this to limit results
        //if(val.length < 3) return;
        console.log(val);
        $.get("artservice.cfc?method=getart&returnformat=json", {term:val}, function(res) {
            var dataList = $("#searchresults");
            dataList.empty();
            if(res.DATA.length) {
                for(var i=0, len=res.DATA.length; i<len; i++) {
                    var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", res.DATA[i][0]);
                    dataList.append(opt);
                }

            }
        },"json");
    });

}

})
```

and the autocomplete works as per the example I linked to.

I am trying to parse this as my datasource:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":1,"params":{"q":"*a*","wt":"json"}},"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"13","body":"Hi guys\r\n\r\nCould you please help me.\r\n\r\nCheers,\r\n\r\nTest Three","title":["Patience"],"_version_":1427207573191262208},{"id":"45","body":"Has been implemented!","title":["Validation"],"_version_":1427207573192310784}]}}
```

I am trying to get the 'Body' to auto-complete in the datalist.  I'm not sure how to get it to work with this more complex json data.

Comment: There is a `getJSON()`method in jQuery for dealing with JSON data.

Comment: iterate through `res.response.docs` using **for..in loop** and see `res.response.docs[i].body` where i is looping variable. I haven't tried that, But, I think it'll give the required result.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.

Is it possible to get it working using code like that in the tutorial?  It's working already with the simple json data.  Is it possible to get it to work with the 'nested' json data?